# Android - replacement for deprecated Notification class

Tags: android, android-notifications

I was wondering what I could use to replace the `deprecated Notification class` and the `setLatestEventInfo()` method.  It's not recognizing the `setLatestEventInfo()` method.

Here is the current code I have:

```
public void makeForeground() {
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.servicename), System.currentTimeMillis());
  notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.servicename), this.lang[134], PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, UIActivity.class), 0));
  startForeground(2, notification);
}
```

What can I replace this with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450449/setlatesteventinfo-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can use NotificationCompat for replacing Notification.

You can read it here more:

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
2. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html
3. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html

Comment: can you provide me an example for starting Foreground service. They are still using setLatestEventInfo on documentation site.