# cannot Resolve symbol (contentIntent)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I created an app few years ago, however, I just updated Android Studios, therefore, my code for the notification is not working as Android does not use this in the latest SDK releases I have tried to use `Notification.Builder` with my code, however, I am receiving an error so can someone please help me.

The error I am receiving is `cannot Resolve symbol (contentIntent);`

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Fall Detector")
    .setContentText("Running")
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
builder.build();
Notification notification = builder.getNotification();

mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setLatestEventInfo cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450449/setlatesteventinfo-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Sufian can you please rewrite my method for me as I am struggling. Thank You

Comment: Which error are you receiving when you try the Notification.Builder? (You wrote "some error")

Comment: It is not recognizing contentIntent and .Build. it cannot resolve both of them

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
builder.setContentTitle("Fall Detector")
builder.setContentText("Running")
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
builder.build();

Notification notification = builder.getNotification();

mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Greaper this is not working as it cannot resolve (contentIntent);

Comment: @user8162255 make sure contentIntent a instance is of [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: Greaper  I have rewritten the code check my question, however, it is still saying unable to resolve  (contentIntent);

Comment: @user8162255 Can you make a screenshot of your error? or share more parts of your source code? Cause it should work if you would make your PendingIntent like this `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

where is ur contentIntent variable ? please screen shot